# Hosting MySQL DB Options for Android App

Tags: android, mysql, database, cloud-hosting

I have a mobile app that stores data to a database on the device.

I am looking to have a MySQL db in the cloud that the app can sync with to either upload or retrieve data.

I am searching online and there are many companies/sites that provide hosting.  Can anyone recommend a trusted hosting service to use for db hosting?  Something inexpensive, but reliable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option could be Google 
https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/
Their pricing is 
https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/billing

Comment: Have you used this personally to host a db for an android app?  How is it?

Comment: No I have not used cloud sql